# Poncho in Scotland

Tags: weather-and-climate, clothing, scotland, trekking

At the beginning of this October, we are planning a trip in Scotland. We are mostly interested in trekking in the areas of Middle and North Scotland. 
I was thinking what to buy to protect myself from the rain - I dont have and currently Im not thinking of buying expensise gore-tex clothes etc., that are water-proof (I have some basic low-cost Quechua jacket with NOVADRY technology which has water column of 5000 mm).
I found out, that army ponchos are pretty reliable against the rain - there is for example this one [Czech army poncho](http://www.army-shop.cz/produkty/plastenky---ponca/plastenky---ponca/plastenka-ponco-orig--ceska-armada/3072.html) , which is quite affordable for me.

The question is - is wearing poncho good idea in Scotland? Ive heard, that I might have some problems due to wind in Scotland while wearing poncho. Will I be able to walk with it or not?

If not, could you recommend other way of affordable rain protection?

Comment: Perhaps a good question for outdoors.se. Also, specific product recommendation questions are normally considered off topic for SE.

Comment: You are right, maybe I should move my question there. But regarding the product, I dont really need specific one, I just need to know whether I should take raincoat, poncho or none of these or something else :).

Comment: Note that a cheap raincoat or poncho may be perfectly waterproof, but if it's not breathable and you're moving around, your sweat may make you even more wet than the rain would.

Comment: The inhabitants of Scotland don't seem to have problems with the wind and [clothing that hangs around them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilt).

Comment: Flagged for migration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds to me like your Quecha jacket should do the job - the main advantage of more expensive fabrics is improved breathability etc - it's ppossible for quite cheap materials to be very waterproof. Although investigate the zips - if they're not sealed/taped then water *will* ingress through them in sustained rain.

Be aware that in the hills of the UK, the weather can change very quickly. A sunny and warm day at the base of the hill may turn to a 10m visibility, rain soaked slog by 3/4 of the way up. Ensure you have good navigational equipment (map, compass/GPS) and warm, dry clothing with you at all times. If you can let someone from your accomodation (if any) know the route you are planning on going before you leave, all the better.

If you're determined to go out in all weathers and cover some distance, investigate some waterproof trousers as well. When the wind comes up, or you're walking through the cloud, the rain drenches you all over.

You're sensible to be prepared - [October is one of the rainier months](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/weather/climate/gfh75zeru)

Comment: Thank you for answer. The zips on the jacket are sealed, so it should be good. Regarding the trousers - do you think I should only get the trousers or buy also some water proof leg warmers? My friend recommended me some leg warmers, but since I will have already water proof trousers, it seems to be a waste of space and money.  Also, thanks for the link with weather, its splendid